# How to prevent an unused npm dependency to be installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

So in my project, I require multiple packages, including "dep1".

"dep1" requires another dependency, "dep2".

And "dep2" requires multiple packages, including "dep3".

The problem is, "dep3" is not compatible with the licence I want to use (well actually, with the licence my boss wants to use).

Fortunatly, only one function of "dep2" uses "dep3", and "dep1" does not use this function. So if I remove "dep3" from node_modules, all will go smoothly.

The problem I have is, how to modify package.json to take this into account when doing npm install, and not install this package ?

I am aware I could branch "dep2" to supress the function, and then "dep1" to use the modifies "dep2", but this seems overkill, and I would be dependant of the owner of the packages to accept my branch. I am looking for a solution like 'well, just add the line ignore : "dep3" into package.json', but can't find any.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: As I'm writing this comment current Node.js version is `11.0.0`, it supports ES6 import under `--experimental-modules` flag. After this feature becomes stable you will be able to use tools like [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) to apply "tree shaking" to your files and produce bundle that excludes code that you don't use. Unfortunately, for this to work all modules from the dependency tree should also switch to ES6 import, so we'll have to wait quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way is to remove unwanted dependency from `node_modules` in NPM `postinstall` hook.

Alternatively, a stub can be provided instead of `dep3`. A stub should contain package.json that will identify it as a substitute with matching version:

```
{
  "name": "dep3",
  "version": "VERSION THAT MATCHES DEP2 CONSTRAINT"
}
```

It can be specified as local dependency in `dep`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "dep3": "./dep3-stub",
  ...
```

Or as Git dependency:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "dep3": "github-user-name/dep3-stub",
  ...
```

If version constraint matches, `dep3` stub will be installed and used instead of real package, otherwise `dep2` may install its own copy of `dep3`.

> I am aware I could branch "dep2" to supress the function, and then "dep1" to use the modifies "dep2", but this seems overkill, and I would be dependant of the owner of the packages to accept my branch.

This is a reasonable approach. This is no concern to the owner. `dep2` fork can be used instead of `dep2` NPM package in the same way as shown for `dep3`.